# "Hi animals" — a US expression?

Tags: expressions, american-english, slang

today I got a meesage on facebook by a known guy to me, from US, and the message was like that

> Hi animals, what is the address to the place?

So the question is, the `Hi animals` is it a kind of expression ? and if so, how is interpeted ?

Is it posible to be auto corrector error ?

Comment: I suppose that if he badly mistyped 'Merianos' (especially without a capital) then yes, a presumptuous auto-correct system could have come up with 'animals'.  It's not a common expression to my knowledge. (edit to add - might he have used voice 'recognition'?)

Comment: Actually, with auto-correct on, he might have been trying to say "Hi, animists," or "Hi, criminals."

Comment: Thanks a lot @JHCL. Otherwhise it mean the think that I understand eh ? :)

Comment: @SvenYargs, thanks for your reply. Due to your comment, the `animists` means something ? I try to find a translation of it, but I cannot.

Comment: Animists are people who believe in nature spirits; animism is what used to be called a primitive religion. But joking aside, I think that the U.S. guy may very well have intended to say "Hi, animals," for obscure reasons of his own. Why not ask him what he meant by the phrase?

Comment: I already asked then, but because the english it is not my native language, I don't know if they say something else that's not real. Anywy, thanks a lof for your assistance :)

Comment: People call people using a lot of names, especially dog-related names as mostly curses. Curses become friendler if spoken among close friends or people in the same race. If you are close enough to him, I don't see any reason why he cannot call you animals. Little chance I see that he mistyped animals. I don't think it is common expression, though.

Comment: Calling friends *animals*, as in *party animals*, was common among young (college-aged) men in the early 80s here in the US. For a quintessentially illustration, watch *Animal House*.

Comment: You could adopt it as your new nickname or [*handle*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/handle) from now on :) Go for the plural noun though, it's less derogative to my ear.

Comment: Certainly it could be a variation on "Hi guys".

Comment: Whatever the meaning, intention, or origin of the phrase here, it is not particularly American, IMO.

Comment: @Drew - Things such as informal greetings between "pals" are highly idiosyncratic, and may come and go within a relatively small group.  I'm relatively certain I've heard (in the US) "animals" as a substitute for "guys" on a few occasions (though not recently).

Comment: @HotLicks: That you've heard it in the US does not imply that it is only or mainly American. I'm pretty sure such informal greetings for pals have been heard in Britain, France, China,... Substituting "*animals*" for "*guys*" is, well, pretty natural in some contexts.

Comment: @Drew - I didn't say that it was unique to the US, just that "not particularly American" is an inaccurate description, if by that you mean to imply that the usage would be unusual in the US.

Comment: @HotLicks: No, sorry. I meant that I do not expect it to be particular to the US. IOW, I meant that it is not American, in particular; it is not **especially** American. (It's interesting that there are two ways to read the use of *particularly* or *especially*, here, in part depending on which word is emphasized.)

Comment: @Drew - I would have said "specifically".

Comment: @HotLicks: I think that has the same problem. But rephrasing I'm sure it can be made clear what was meant. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of similar usage appears in this excerpt from Richard Rupp, [*Death & Taxes*](https://books.google.com/books?id=m1p5CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT192&dq=%22hello+animals%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC4Q6AEwBDgeahUKEwilicTB26bIAhVFO4gKHf-pAwc#v=onepage&q=%22hello%20animals%22&f=false) (2015):

> It was a little after seven-thirty in the evening when Dick's flight landed at Lackland Air Force Base, just west of San Antonio. The Gulfstream pulled up to a hangar, where a sister FBI Gulfstream was parked. The aircraft's stairs were lowered, and Dick was directed into the adjacent hangar. Waiting for him in an office was the rest of his team, who had arrived an hour ahead of him.
>
> “**Hello, Animals!** Good to see you.”
>
> Daniel asked, “Why are we at this air force base?”
>
> “Because this is where we catch our flight to Mexico City.”

Here the character Dick uses *Animals* as an affectionate, highly informal name for his colleagues just before they embark on a secret mission. The usage resembles the habit that some people (in the United States) have of calling their friends "dawgs." The term is not intended as an insult; it's spoken in a tone of comfortable familiarity. Be that as it may, "Hi, animals" is by no means a common way to address friends or colleagues in the United Sates.